# Showing icons of files and folders in an aspx page inside the sharepoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, icons, spgridview

```
 I am using spgridview to show the files and folders of document library in an
```

aspx page. Now i want to display the files and folders along with icons in spgridview.

Can any have an idea how to do it?

Comment: I see you reverted the edit where @Fun Mun Pieng fixed your formatting. FYI, when you use four spaces to indent, it formats your text as a code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take help from following post this also talks on similar issue
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010programming/thread/43932de2-296c-4de4-a615-24869c329839